# JavaFX on Raspi Linux - Stages do not get a window

Tags: java, linux, javafx, window

Am currently working on a cross-platform application based on JavaFX. On Windows it runs smoothly, but on Linux on a Raspberry Pi 3, stages (aka the JFX window) do not get a window frame.
Instead the entire background which would be outside, showing the Linux desktop or other windows, turns black (including the taskbar) and not even the Alt+Tab command works anymore.
The bar with the close button doesn't show either (only the content of the stage alone).

The stage is explicitly set to "primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);" and no errors occur during execution of the program.

In the end it looks like this: [image]

The Raspberry Pi had to be manually equipped with JFX support as it is not standard. Could it be that some component responsible for windows is missing?
Anyone ever encountered something similar?

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the OpenJDK Wiki:

> Note that the default configuration of JavaFX on the Raspberry Pi does
>   not use X11. Instead JavaFX works directly with the display
>   framebuffer and input devices. So you should not have the X11 desktop
>   running when starting JavaFX.

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi#OpenJFXontheRaspberryPi-Stoppinganapplication

Comment: Ahh, alright! Okey, that makes sense. Not perfect for my case but at least I know that nothing is broken.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is of additional help for you: http://openjfx-dev.openjdk.java.narkive.com/5qz5qwJH/is-a-desktop-experience-on-arm-with-x11-possible